# Excel bottom border for every categoric batch events

Tags: excel, border

I have this Sample datasets:

[image]

I wanted to give bottom border for each of the end of batch_events like this:

[image]

How to reproduce this to apply it to all of batch events without adding it manually? (This is for the sample datasets) https://file.lu/d/yt6

Thankyou in Advances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below formula in CF custom formula rule-

```
=$A1<>$A2
```

[image]